# when logs of a file is older then 24hrs , copy its content to a newfile

Tags: linux

linux cmd, when logs of  a file is older then 24hrs , copy its content to a newfile

every 2 or 5 hrs when we check specific file "samplelogs" and if the logs in it are older then 24hrs, copy its content by createing new file with day example "smaplelog_Monday" , "samplelog_Tuesday"

below is the sample logs in the file
Backup failure::Master:banc4adp01.zeedev.best.com.au||Host:aut0sap65-b.test.sample.com.as||Policy:t3-dev-em-unx-3m-2||Schedule:Full||Error:48||Date:Sun Aug 23 21:02:42 AEST 2020
Backup failure::Master:banc4adp01.zeedev.best.com.au||Host:aut0sap65-b.test.sample.com.as||Policy:t3-dev-em-unx-3m-2||Schedule:Full||Error:48||Date:Sun Aug 23 21:02:40 AEST 2020
Backup failure::Master:banc4adp01.zeedev.best.com.au||Host:aut0sap65-b.test.sample.com.as||Policy:t3-dev-kn-unx-3m-04||Schedule:Differential-Inc||Error:58||Date:Sun Aug 23 18:04:36 AEST 2020
Backup failure::Master:banc4adp01.zeedev.best.com.au||Host:aut0sap65-b.test.sample.com.as||Policy:t3-dev-kn-unx-3m-04||Schedule:Differential-Inc||Error:58||Date:Sun Aug 23 18:04:36 AEST 2020
Backup failure::Master:banc4adp01.zeedev.best.com.au||Host:aut0sap65-b.test.sample.com.as||Policy:t3-dev-em-unx-3m-2||Schedule:Full||Error:58||Date:Sun Aug 23 21:04:34 AEST 2020
Backup failure::Master:banc4adp01.zeedev.best.com.au||Host:aut0sap65-b.test.sample.com.as||Policy:t3-dev-em-unx-3m-2||Schedule:Full||Error:58||Date:Sun Aug 23 21:04:32 AEST 2020
Backup failure::Master:banc4adp01.zeedev.best.com.au||Host:aut0sap65-b.test.sample.com.as||Policy:t3-dev-em-unx-3m-2||Schedule:Full||Error:58||Date:Sun Aug 23 21:04:30 AEST 2020

Comment: Use the formatting tools provided to format your question (and include an actual question while you're at it). Are you simply looking for somebody to do your work? Post salary and job description.

Comment: so you work when salary is given....send me your profile will check let you know the suitable Job .....hmmmmm

Answer (score 1):

The question is not quite clear, but you may want to look at logrotate which allows to implement many log rotation policy.
Here is the man page for reference https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html

Comment: Thanks David for your kind response, will check the log rotate ink and let you know if works. thanks again